# how to fix Unused import statement when importing module

Tags: python, pycharm, pyinstaller, python-import, interpreter

geniuses, today I tried to convert py to exe, but it doesn't work and I got this: a Project output will not be moved to output folder Complete.

so I tried to uninstall pyinstaller with cmd, and after that my python project got broken and I got this:

Unused import statement 'from io import BytesIO'

Unused import statement 'from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile'

Unused import statement 'from sqlite3 import Error'

Unused import statement 'Calendar

'

and when I am trying to re-installing modules by cmd so I can use the libraries correctly and import things from them I got this error too:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement (module name)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for (module name)

so how to correctly install them again and use them with no problem

Comment: Please post code as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @Barmar its ok but you can see i wrote the errors in text.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. But if we can't read the code that caused the error, it's hard to tell you how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned error may indicate that you are running an old version of Python (likely Python 2 when Python 3 is required).

This can be fixed by running the command like this

```
python3 -m pip install <package name>
```

If this is not the case, you may have to go in and start manually installing all dependencies if this is not being done automatically. This can happen if it was installed like `pip install --user <package name>` to my knowledge.

Edit: do note that the unused import messages are NOT the errors. Those are simply what’s letting you know that a module was not used.

Comment: thank you, I really appreciate your answer, it  appears that there is a problem with the interpreter am using in my project, I can't find the one that I used before uninstalling pyinstaller